# Basic SQL*Plus Report: Break On Command Not Working as Intended

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am learning how to write basic SQL*Plus Reports.

While practicing, I ran into trouble with the BREAK ON command and am unsure how to proceed.

For reference, the table being used is called "Newspaper" and it contains the name of a Feature in a newspaper, what section that feature is in, and what page that feature is on.

When running the following report, SQL*Plus returns the results as expected:

```
rem Newspaper Report

ttitle 'Newspaper Features by Section'
btitle 'Hot off the Presses'

column feature format a15 word_wrapped
column section format a7 
column page format 99
column feature heading 'Feature'
column section heading 'Section'
column page heading 'Page'

break on section skip 1

set linesize 80
set pagesize 40
set newpage 0 
set feedback off

spool test.sql

select section, feature, page from newspaper
order by section;

spool off
```

The output:

```
Section Feature         Page
------- --------------- ----
A       National News      1
        Editorials        12

B       Bridge             2
        Movies             4
        Modern Life        1
        Television         7

C       Comics             4
        Weather            2

D       Sports             1

E       Business           1

F       Obituaries         6
        Classified         8
        Doctor Is In       6
        Births             7
```

In this example, SQL*Plus skips one line whenever it reaches a new feature. This is how it is expected to work.

However, when I execute the following report, my results aren't formatted the way they should be:

```
rem Newspaper Report

ttitle 'Newspaper Features by Page'
btitle 'Hot off the Presses'

column feature format a15 word_wrapped
column section format a7 
column page format 99
column feature heading 'Feature'
column section heading 'Section'
column page heading 'Page'

break on page skip 1

set linesize 80
set pagesize 40
set newpage 0 
set feedback off

spool test.sql

select page, feature, section from newspaper
order by page;

spool off
```

The output:

```
Page Feature         Section
---- --------------- -------
   1 Modern Life     B
     Sports          D
     National News   A
     Business        E
   2 Weather         C
     Bridge          B
   4 Movies          B
     Comics          C
   6 Doctor Is In    F
     Obituaries      F
   7 Television      B
     Births          F
   8 Classified      F
  12 Editorials      A
```

No lines were skipped when the page changed. Am I doing something wrong or is the command limited in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the problem is the column name being "Page"; since page is a BREAK ACTION. Can you try aliasing the column to something other than "page" and try that: For example:

```
column page_temp heading 'Page'

break on page_temp skip 1

set linesize 80
set pagesize 40
set newpage 0 
set feedback off

spool test.sql

select page page_temp, feature, section from newspaper
order by page;
```